# Why onAccessibilityEvent(..) method of AccessibilityService is reading the same view many times?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am using AccessibilityService to determine the text and coordinates of views of any current application running in android device.
On every event onAccessibilityEvent(...) runs but i don't know how to control these events. I have used event.getSource() to get the result of every window content changed. The xml settings of my AccessibilityService is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged|typeViewFocused"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:packageNames="com.whatsapp"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"

/>
```

and the onAccessibilityEvent(...) is:

```
@Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {


        Log.e("MyService: ","Get Source output: "+event.getSource());
        String get_cord= String.valueOf(event.getSource());

         Log.e("MyService: ","Window id is: "+window_ID);


    }
```

and the output which i am getting is(I have highlighted the text value in bold:

```
08-18 19:34:29.055 20131-20131/com.example.root.without_root E/MyService:: Get Source output: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@801b6813; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 548, 46); boundsInScreen: Rect(144, 1095 - 692, 1141); packageName: com.device; className: android.widget.TextView; **text: Samsung**; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.whatsapp:id/name; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_SELECTION - null]

08-18 19:34:29.058 20131-20131/com.example.root.without_root E/MyService:: Get Source output: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@801b6813; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 548, 46); boundsInScreen: Rect(144, 1095 - 692, 1141); packageName: com.device; className: android.widget.TextView; **text: Samsung**; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.whatsapp:id/name; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_SELECTION - null]

08-18 19:34:29.061 20131-20131/com.example.root.without_root E/MyService:: Get Source output: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@801b6813; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 548, 46); boundsInScreen: Rect(144, 1095 - 692, 1141); packageName: com.whatsapp; className: android.widget.TextView; **text: Samsung**; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.device:id/name; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_SELECTION - null]
08-18 19:34:29.064 20131-20131/com.example.root.without_root E/MyService:: Get Source output: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@801b6bd4; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 548, 38); boundsInScreen: Rect(144, 1141 - 692, 1179); packageName: com.whatsapp; className: android.widget.TextView; text: ☺; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.whatsapp:id/status; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_SELECTION - null]
```

Now you can see that it ran 3 times for only 1 view But i want it to run only for single time for one view. Please help me to find out how can i make this possible?

I have already tried with changing the values of accessibilityEventTypes in xml from "typeAllMasks" to "typeWindowContentChanged" and "typeViewFocused" but nothing helped me out.

I have also tried to setup flags in onAccessibilityEvent(...) of AccessibilityService but that also didn't worked because the service keeps on running everytime(It would be great if somebody can make it work).

Please do tell me how can i make it to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessibility events happen very frequently. So, first, I would like you to consider whether or not you really want to ignore these events. What user experience issue are you looking to address?

In particular, issues that are going to happen a lot are windowContentChanged events and viewFocused events. One thing you could consider doing is throttling events.  The following change to your service config xml will limit each specific event type to happening once ever half a second.

> The event notification timeout is useful to avoid propagating events to the client too frequently since this is accomplished via an expensive interprocess call. One can think of the timeout as a criteria to determine when event generation has settled down.

So, your service config xml would look like this:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged|typeViewFocused"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
android:packageNames="com.whatsapp"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
android:notificationTimeout="500"
/>
```

Notably, however, you could miss events. So, if you're relying on keeping in sync with those events, you would want to se this lower. It's a balancing act.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have edited the  xml file as per u said and i got some better results. In notificationTimeout i set its value to only "1" , now  i am getting one TextView value 1-2 times instead 5-7 times. So is there any way by which i can reduce it to only 1 time. By setting its value to "2" it is missing some of the textviews.

Comment: i need somewhere in between 1 and 2, but we cannot set float values in android:notificationTimeout="", i have tried with adding one float value in dimen but that resulted in one error that float values are not allowed in "notificationTimeout" .

Comment: This value is milliseconds. So, it's unlikely that a "float" would help, and at that point you have a race condition. What setting to "1" does, is just limit the events that happen in immediate succession, which is good. But, no, you cannot limit any further, without risking losing events... hence, race condition. Any further logic would need to be done in your code.

Comment: I managed to get the results without settiing notificationTimeout in the xml configuration.

Comment: I removed the notificationTimeout because sometimes i was not getting the data i want. I have set the timers for my tasks which runs before onAccessibilityEvent(..) can do further anything to ruin my code , thanks anyways.